# Alamofire 4.0.1 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 xCode 8 SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3, xcode8

My project worked perfectly with cocoapods 1.0.1 and Alamofire branch "swift3". But today i've updated cocoapods to 1.1.0 and updated alamofire to version 4.0.1 from Master branch and got linker error for x86-64 (simulator) build:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   Alamofire.request (Alamofire.URLConvertible, method :
>   Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters : [Swift.String : Any]?, encoding :
>   Alamofire.ParameterEncoding, headers : [Swift.String : Swift.String]?)
>   -> Alamofire.DataRequest", referenced from
>
> protocol witness table for Swift.String : Alamofire.URLConvertible in
>   Alamofire", referenced from:

But for device (arm targets) everything works well.

Tried to deintegrate pods, remove all scripts and folders and install again - but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution:

Had to remove derivedData manually and restart xCode after clean.

(Facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

And the install your pods again

Alternatively, remove the pods and use Swift Package Manager instead.